# Why CSS from resources is not working in spring jsp page?

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

This is my jsp page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--here the title Go-->
    <title></title>
   <%--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" >
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" >
      --%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container main">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 ownPic">
          <img src="no-profile-female.jpg" alt="">
          <input type="file">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Father's Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Father Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mother's Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Father Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">National ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="National ID">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="22">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Blood Group</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select your Blood Type</option>
            <option value="">A +</option>
            <option value="">A -</option>
            <option value="">B +</option>
            <option value="">B -</option>
            <option value="">O +</option>
            <option value="">O -</option>
            <option value="">AB +</option>
            <option value="">AB -</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-control" placeholder="Select your Blood Type">
            <option value="">Select your Gender</option>
            <option value="">Male</option>
            <option value="">Female</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address (Current)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="name" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address (Permarent)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="name" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PGT/PHD</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">University</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passing Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Result</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Master's Degree</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">University</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passing Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Result</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bacholor's Degree</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">University</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passing Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Result</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">HSC</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">College Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passing Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Result</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SSC</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">School Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passing Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Result</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Joining Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>


      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employment Experience</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="checkbox">Yes
          <input type="checkbox">No
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">From</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">To</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">From</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">To</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">From</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">To</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Year</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Training</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="checkbox">Yes
          <input type="checkbox">No
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Organization</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Topic</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Duration</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Organization</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Topic</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Duration</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="button" name="button">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-reset btn-lg" type="button" name="button">Reset</button>
      </div>

</form>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am adding CSS on resources folder. It should look like : [This the require form](https://eerie00.github.io/asha/) But it looks like : [This is my jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2qXg.png) .

my dispatcher-servlet is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="EmployeeRegistrationForm.controller" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/css/"
    cache-period="31556926"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

Then how can I solve this problem?

my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>SpringExamples</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>SpringExamples</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringExamples</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <name>SpringExamples</name>
 <description></description>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <webResources>
      <resource>
       <directory>WebContent</directory>
      </resource>
     </webResources>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <properties>
  <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Css Not loading. Specify the Correct Path.

Comment: This is the correct path. My css files are in css folder,which is in resources folder @J

Comment: Check the File is Loading Correctly From the Inspects in Chrome.

Comment: @JeesKDenny , yes. in inspect , it shows **http://localhost:8080/resources/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()** . But why?

Comment: check the correspond folder and be sure the file exist in the folder and the name of the file should be style.css. Is the bootstrap.min.css loads correctly?

Comment: @JeesKDenny , No. it doesn't load correctly

Comment: I have not enough point to chat . :( I am new here.

Comment: @OUNAsh show me your project dir structure. web-inf, resources, java dir structure.

Comment: @OUNAsh also show your web.xml

Comment: @ScanQR , I have added web.xml and pom.xml

Comment: @OUNAsh what about dir structure? can you add a image of your dir structure as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your resources in `WebContent` directory and not in `src/main/resources`

Please move your all `static` resources from `src/main/resources` to `WebContent/resources` directory.

This will allow `spring` to scan the static resource properly and then you can rebuild your application.

```
 <!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This will tell `DispatcherServlet` to delegate the `resource` scanning to correct servlet.

Comment: Thank you soo much.I have replace the resource folder from src/main to webapp and it works!!!!

Comment: @OUNAsh glad to know that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: replace your resource mapping with the flollowing in dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/"
cache-period="31556926"/>
```

OR

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
cache-period="31556926"/>
```

Comment: where did you kept your resources directory with in your project?

Comment: src/main/resources/css

Answer (score 0):

change 
     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">`

to this
      `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources   /css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">`

Also put this in dispatcher-servlet as answered by[ScanQR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6887084/scanqr)

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```